# Modeling User Data for SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am working on an web app in PHP which will work with user data in MySQL.

The difficulty at developing a sql-structure is now to design the relations modular. So that it is easy to delete and add relations to other tables.

My first thought was to create a OneToMany relation from the user table to another table. This other table links than finally the whole data structure down.

```
user_receiver-table:
user_id | receiver_id | description
1       | 2           | relation to characteristics
1       | 3           | relation to user logs
2       | 4           | relation to picture table
```

Is this thought generally good?

How do I hide different tables behind one column (and its id)?

Comment: just remember that using lots of JOIN can slow down performance

Comment: Hi,

how do you menage to relate users to other tables without hardcoding. So that you can add and remove relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data model reflects your knowledge of the problem you are trying to solve. As your understanding of the problem evolves (and/or external actors impose new requirements), changes in the data model are inevitable. You won't be able to *completely* automate this process no matter what.

That being said, you should be able to achieve some measure of "generality", using one of the following options:

### 1. Inheritance

For example:

[image]

### 2. [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

A *very* simplified representation of that would be:

[image]

Both have pros and cons, but in a nutshell, the option (1) is less generic but more "type safe".

Comment: Hi, does sounds good. So the point is to use the same FK for all tables. Do you know if this is doctrine compatible?
Regards

Comment: @user1246987 Sorry, no. I'm not familiar with the Doctrine project, nor with PHP for that matter - this answer is purely from the database modelling perspective.

Comment: Ok thank ya. Will look around how I could implement the pattern into an ORM. Regards

Comment: Ok I know decided to create a one to one relation from the User-Table which contains all login-related data to User-Composite what contains all private data like name, birth, and so on.
Than I can work with the user-composite and have less dependency to the user component

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of views.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-views/

However you can not add values to a view when it is related to many tables.

"For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table."